# Refresh the runtime on android

Tags: java, android

Is there is any way to refresh the Runtime object which is got by calling Runtime.getRuntime()?

I was using this for checking root permission on my application by executing the su command. It seems that even if I temporarily unroot/root the device using some application(i used  [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zachspong.temprootremover)) Runtime.getRuntime() is not knowing it. To make it aware that su command is available/not-available is to restart the application.